# Why is the promise resolved like this? (Using notify callback)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I was checking the code of a Stomp Chat client using angular and the developer created a service caled **receive** which returns a promise. Then in the contoller, it resolves the promise but... I don't understand the structure.

```
ChatService.receive().then(null, null, function(message) {
  $scope.messages.push(message);
});
```

As far as I understand, there are two parameters for the then, the onSuccess function, and the onError function. Then why are the first two null and the thrid is the one that handles the success? and if I needed to handle the error, how could I do it?

Comment: Does receive() return a custom promise?  Could be some library-baked promise-handling that differs from the normal then(resolve [,reject]) signature

Comment: my guess would be something along the lines of then(resolve [,reject, always])?

Comment: What promise implementation are you using? There are some that did use a third parameter for **notification** callbacks, but that's deprecated almost everywhere.

Comment: This is not a behavior of plain JS. Maybe the third callback is a `finally` callback, which is called always, in case of success of failure. He puts is code there so in both cases he will have the message there. 
But if you see inside the source code which libraries he is using, there will be for sure a third party library for promises which handles a third parameter and you will find the explanation there

Comment: the third parameter to .then() is progressCallback which is called when deferred notifies progress. You can check this link:: https://g00glen00b.be/spring-angular-sockjs/ that provides some explanation.

Comment: @Bergi The promise is a `$q.defered();`, an usual AngularJS service. And the **receive** service is  `service.receive = function () {
            return listener.promise;
        };` where `listener=$q.defer();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument is the `notifyCallBack` function.

From the Docs:

> ### The Promise API
>
> #### Methods
>
> - `then(successCallback, [errorCallback], [notifyCallback])` – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.
>
>   This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via the return value of the `successCallback`, `errorCallback` (unless that value is a promise, in which case it is resolved with the value which is resolved in that promise using [promise chaining](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-promises-queues)). It also notifies via the return value of the `notifyCallback` method. The promise cannot be resolved or rejected from the `notifyCallback` method. The `errorCallback` and `notifyCallback` arguments are optional.
>
> [— AngularJS $q Service API Reference (The Promise API)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api)

#### NOTE:

Promise notifications do not compose well[<sup>1</sup>](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseprogressonprogress) and are not part of [ES6 Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Instead, consider using [rxJS Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rxjs/info) which are used extensively in [Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/info) and provide a better path for the future.